# Firebase field/child access restriction

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am currently developing a javascript based application which stores relevant user data in a field under their name, However I do not want other users to write/read to other fields which do not belong to them, to achieve this, I wish to restrict user access to field names. Is there a rule configuration that allows me to do this???

Comment: Why JavaScript? Why not just use a database and SQL?

Comment: needs to be live, firebase is good for live databasing

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart). To restrict users to only write to their own data, when they're authenticated, something like this should do the trick:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without authentication, I just want users to not be able to get a list of the names of the fields/objects

Comment: Yes, here's code that restricts the client from completely writing or reading to something. The only way you could see/edit the data then, is through the firebase console or the admin package from something like Node.JS Put this code into the rules section:  {
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}